# Is there any way to refresh pull request merge status in Azure DevOps REST API?

Tags: c#, azure-devops-rest-api

Using the Azure DevOps REST API in C#, I'm creating a pull request and then attempting to complete it like this (simplified):

```cs
var pullRequest = new GitPullRequest { 
    Title = "My PR",
    SourceRefName = "refs/heads/my",
    TargetRefName = "refs/heads/master",
    Commits = commits
};

pullRequest = await gitClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(pullRequest, repositoryId);

await Task.Delay(3000);

if (pullRequest.MergeStatus == PullRequestAsyncStatus.Succeeded) {
    var pr2 = new GitPullRequest
    {
        LastMergeSourceCommit = pullRequest.LastMergeSourceCommit,
        Status = PullRequestStatus.Completed
    };            
    var result = await gitClient.UpdatePullRequestAsync(pullRequest, pullRequest.Repository.Id, pullRequest.pullRequestId);
}
```

This works fine if there's no conflicts. But if the pull request has conflicts, MergeStatus will be Conflicts. Now, let's assume someone resolves those conflicts manually and the PR is ready to be merged.

After resolving conflicts I get the pull request again

```cs
var pullRequest = await gitClient.GetPullRequestByIdAsync(pullRequestId);
```

pullRequest.MergeStatus is still Conflicts, even though UI is showing green.

Is there a way to refresh MergeStatus once it has been set to Conflicts? I tried updating the pull request by setting MergeStatus to Queued. Or is it a missing feature in the API?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you got through this, so just in case someone else comes looking (like I did today) this worked for me.

```
var prOriginal = gitClient.CreatePullRequestAsync(
    new GitPullRequest() {
        SourceRefName = $"refs/heads/{Input.SrcBranch}",
        TargetRefName = $"refs/heads/{Input.TgtBranch}",
        Title = Input.Title,
        Description = Input.Description
    },
    tgtRepo.Id).Result;

Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
var statusRetry = 0;
var prTest = gitClient.GetPullRequestAsync(
    tgtRepo.Id, 
    prOriginal.PullRequestId).Result;
while(PullRequestAsyncStatus.Succeeded != prTest.MergeStatus) {
    // TODO decide when to quit.
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    prTest = gitClient.GetPullRequestAsync(
        tgtRepo.Id, 
        prOriginal.PullRequestId).Result; 
}
Debug.WriteLine($"MergeStatus: {prTest.MergeStatus}");
```

MergeStatus came back succeeded soon after I resolved the problems online. Now if I can get those conflicts resolved using the api I'll be in great shape.